# How can I efficiently calculate the mathematical limit for average number of rounds in a game?

Tags: javascript, math

For an odds calculator for a board game, I need to calculate how many rounds a battle will last on average. Because there is a possibility that both sides in the battle will miss, a battle can theoretically last forever. Therefore I cannot traverse all branches, but need to calculate a mathematical limit. By verifying with a simulator, I have found that the following function correctly approximates the average number of rounds left:

```
// LIMIT could be any number, the larger it is, the more accurate the result.
const LIMIT = 100;
// r is the number of rounds left if at least 1 of the sides hit
// x is the chance that both sides miss and the round count gets increased,
// but the battle state stays the same.
function approximateLimitForNumberOfRounds(r: number, x: number) {
  let approx = r / (1 - x);
  // n -> infinity
  for (let n = 1; n < LIMIT; n++) {
    approx += x ** n;
  }
  return approx;
}
```

How can I modify this function to exactly calculate the number of rounds left, instead of approximating it? (noting that since `x` is a chance, it is contained in `(0, 1)` or `0 < x < 1`).

Comment: 'correctly approximates' How? And how would you do it on paper (would you take the limit as `LIMIT` grows?)

Comment: Also, I just expanded your line for `approx = ` in the loop and it just evaluates to `approx = approx - approx*odds + approx*odds + odds` which then becomes `approx = approx + odds` - so you can just use a sum?

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, but I will add some examples.

Comment: How is the approximation mathematically calculated/defined - and the limit as LIMIT grows simply refers back to your comment at the top of the code that the larger LIMIT is the more accurate it is (i.e. taking the mathematical limit to find an expression for when LIMIT is infinite)

Comment: Okay thanks, that's a nice simplification that I didn't see. I edited the code snippet with that.

Comment: wvdz I presume since x is a chance, then it's <1 ?

Comment: Yes, exactly `0 < x < 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can note that `approx` takes on the following values:

```
r / (1 - x) # I refer to this as 'a' below
a + x
a + x + x^2
a + x + x^2 + x^3
a + x + x^2 + ... + x^n
```

Thus, we can simplify the mathematical expression to be:

```
a + (the sum of x^k from k = 1 to k = n)
```

Next, we must note that the sequence `x + x^2 + x^3 ...` forms a geometric sequence with first term `x` and common ratio `x`. Since `x` is bounded by `0 < x < 1`, this will have a limiting sum, namely:

```
x + x^2 + x^3 + ... x^inf = x/(1-x)
```

<sub>(this obviously fails when `x = 1`, as well as in the original function where `r / (1 - x)` is taken, but in that case, you will simply have the sum as infinity and `approx` would escape to infinity if it were not `undefined`; so I am assuming that `x != 1` in the following calculations and `x = 1` can be / has been dealt with separately).</sub>

Now, since we have both a single expression for `x + x^2 + ...` to infinity, and a single expression for `approx` that includes `x + x^2 + ...` then we can write `approx` using both of these two facts:

```
approx = r / (1 - x) + x / (1 - x)
approx = (r + x) / (1 - x)
```

And there you go! That is the mathematical equivalent of the logic you've outlined in your question, compressed to a single statement (which I believe is correct :)).

Comment: @Ouroborus check the output again - that fraction has (x - 1) as the denominator, which is the negation of (1 - x) as in my answer - they're equivalent. Here is the difference between that output and my fraction: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28-x%29%28x+-+1%29+-+%28x%29%281+-+x%29 (it's 0)

Comment: Wow, that is amazing. I have to admit I cannot fully follow the reasoning, but I verified that this gives the correct result. Thanks!

Comment: @wvdz No worries, I am happy to explain it more than that if you'd like, but in short: You can observe that the sequence you're adding forms `x, x^2, x^3, ..., x^n` (a geometric progression with both the first and common term `x`), and since `x` is less than `1` and greater than `0`, adding all of the terms (i.e. `x + x^2 + x^3 ...`) is a 'limiting sum' (high school maths). This has a common expression/formula which we then sub in place of `x + x^2 + x^3 ...` and then simplify the resultant fractions, and that gives you your answer! (again, let me know if you more detail and I'll help you out)

Comment: Yup, highschool maths, that's pretty much my level, but some parts are a bit rusty :) It looks like magic at first, but I understand the reasoning now, thanks.

Comment: Glad to assist @wvdz :) please let me know if any issues persist! (for obvious reasons x != 1 as then we have a division by zero which is a bad idea :P)

Comment: x cannot be 1, because that would mean that the probability is 100% that both parties will miss, which means there is nothing to hit and the battle is over. So I guess conceptually the answer should be 0 in that case, but my code will never reach this function.